# C# ASP.NET MVC : how do I limit the number of characters passed in through a POST request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am using `.cshtml` to send a `POST` request to my controller. The following is my `.cshtml` form.

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostTest, "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="number" name="test" min="0" max="99999" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

The number entered by the user will be sent to the controller as shown below:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostTest(int test) 
{
     // process the data here
}
```

I am only expecting about 5 digits for the number that is passed in. However, if I enter a very large value with like 100 digits, the program crashes because I am using `int` data type. Even if I change to `long` data type, this problem still occurs if I enter a large number. I think the program crashes when the argument was passed in way beyond its limit.

I did set a range to limit the data passed in from 0 to 99999. However, I want to prevent such a scenario in my controller action too. Is that possible?

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What if insted of passing a int you passed a string and then convert to number and throw a error if the number is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use string instead of int. Then `check if it convert into a int` and if it `is in the desired range`. try this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostTest(string test)
    {
        int number = -1;
        var result = int.TryParse(test, out number);
        if (result && number >= 0 && number <= 99999)
            return Ok(number);
        else
            return BadRequest("the number is in the wrong format ... ");
    }
```

Comment: So it is not possible to use it as `type='number'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a request data object and in this creating use Fluent Validation for this field it will give you an error after that you can send after this error BadRequest.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTest {
    [Range(0, 2147483646)]
    public int myproperty {get;set;}
}



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostTest(MyTest test) 
    {
         // process the data here
    }
```

Comment: More info at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0